# How to find lines between body tags in Python?

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm wondering how can I find lines between some html tags, that are in multiple lines? Like this:

```
<body...
sth...
sth...
sth...
</body...
```

How to get all those 'sth' lines?

I was trying to find the answer for 'searching between the lines' and similar, but beside some weird tricks for BeautifulSoup - nothing useful.

Comment: use `html.parser` or `beautifulsoup` to extract them. When you deal with formatted data, help yourself with the format.

Comment: Can you post your attempted beautifulsoup code?

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<body>
sth...
sth...
sth...
</body>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print soup.find('body').prettify()
```

[Check out more about BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)